# SDL_DisplayFormat works, but not SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-1.2

The following code is intended to display a green square on a black background.  It executes, but the green square does not show up.  However, if I change `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha` to `SDL_DisplayFormat` the square is rendered correctly.

So what don't I understand?  It seems to me that I am creating `*surface` with an alpha mask and I am using `SDL_MapRGBA` to map my green color, so it would be consistent to use `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha` as well.

(I removed error-checking for clarity, but none of the SDL API calls fail in this example.)

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(
        640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF
    );

    SDL_Surface *temp = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(
        SDL_HWSURFACE, 100, 100, 32, 0, 0, 0,
        ( SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN ? 0x000000ff : 0xff000000 )
    );

    SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha( temp );

    SDL_FreeSurface( temp );

    SDL_FillRect(
        surface, &surface->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGBA(
            screen->format, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff
        )
    );

    SDL_Rect r;
    r.x = 50;
    r.y = 50;

    SDL_BlitSurface( surface, NULL, screen, &r );

    SDL_Flip( screen );

    SDL_Delay( 1000 );

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong format for SDL_MapRGBA.  Should have been

```
SDL_FillRect(
    surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGBA(
        surface->format, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff
    )
);
```

(`surface->format` instead of `screen->format`.)  I thought the two would be equivalent.  And they are after calling `SDL_DisplayFormat()`, but *not* after calling `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha()`.  The screen surface doesn't have an alpha channel, so the format is different between the two.

(Cross-posted from [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/41954/sdl-displayformat-works-but-not-sdl-displayformatalpha))